# Нужно ли вручную на JS сжимать AJAX POST из браузера при работе через HTTPS или это делается автоматически?

Tags: ajax, post, ssl, https, gzip

Например я каждую минуту отправляю JSON (20 Кб) на сервер, который записывает в базу данных.
Если я вручную сожму на JS через LZW эти данные и отправлю как двоичные данные, то их размер будет всего 5 Кб.

Нахожу какие-то старые статьи, в которых вкратце говорят, что при соединении через SSL ничего сжимать не надо, так как это делается на уровне протокола. При этом ничего подробного не нашел.

Подскажите пожалуйста, так ли это и где можно уточнить?
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Через SSL ничего сжимать **нельзя**, потому что это снижает безопасность (см. атаку CRIME и подобные), и поэтому современные браузеры этого не делают

Comment: Теоретически может поддерживаться сжатие тела запроса на уровне HTTP, но из-за того, что браузер заранее не знает, поддерживается ли сжатие сервером, он не может отправить сжатый запрос

Comment: Я немного не понимаю по поводу того, что HTTPS ничего не сжимает сам и через HTTPS ничего нельзя отправлять предварительно сжатое. Смысл атаки CRIME мне понятен, но результат непонятен. Сейчас почти все сайты работают через HTTPS - ничего не сжимается нигде и никогда? Что делать тогда? Так и гонять кучу трафика впустую? Я пример привёл с размером в 20 Кб, но он может быть в тысячи раз больше, при этом, в сжатом состоянии - в тысячи раз меньше.

Comment: Большие сжимаемые запросы — это редкость. Вот что не редкость — это большие сжимаемые ответы сервера, в первую очередь статические файлы — вот их активно сжимают. Но к SSL это не имеет отношения

Comment: Сжимать вручную можно. Автоматически браузер ничего не сжимает. CRIME имеет место только когда одновременно сжимаются секретные данные (кука/токен) и данные злоумышленника. В вашем случае это неактуально.

Comment: Раз в минуту 20 кб - это не то, за что стоит бороться, ИМХО. Если бы вы каждую секунду столько отправляли, тогда да, имело бы смысл задуматься. Браузеры не сжимают тело запроса, поэтому для минимизации объемов вы можете пересмотреть структуру запроса. Например, вместо `{"some_int":10,"some_str":"Hello!"}` передавать массив `[10,"Hello"]` - налицо экономия 23-х байт.

Comment: То есть, я правильно понял, что при отправке данных из браузера через защищённые соединения автоматически ничего прозрачно сжиматься не будет?